# how to upload image files to server and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, file-upload, multer

**React.js Node.js Express.js Axios Multer MongoDB Mongoose**

**Wrote this form to register users, the user enters name, email, password, and a file for later use as profile pic/Avatar.
When i tested the form on Postman the opposite has happened, the file was uploaded to the public/uploads/images folder but it didnt post to the user with the rest of the registration data i entered.
But when i tested the form on localhost domain the image filename was saved on the user's Avatar value MongoDB nut was'nt uploaded to the servers folder i chose to upload my uploaded files.**

**wanted end result:
to register user to websites database with all parameters, uploading the image to the server and image filename to users avatar data**

**Register Route**

```
 router.post("/register", upload.single("avatar"), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const validatedValue = await validateRegisterSchema(req.body);
    const user = await findUserByEmail(validatedValue.email);
    if (user) throw "try different email";
    const hashedPassword = await createHash(validatedValue.password);
    validatedValue.password = hashedPassword;
    await createNewUser(validatedValue);
    res.status(201).json({ msg: "user created"});
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ error });
  }
});
```

**Multer**

```
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "./public/uploads/images/");
  },

  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(16, function (err, raw) {
      if (err) return cb(err);

      cb(null, file.originalname);
    });
  },
});


const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype === "image/jpeg" || file.mimetype === "image/png") {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};

const upload = multer({
  storage,
  limit: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 10,
  },
  fileFilter,
});
```

**User Model**

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const usersSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  wishList: { type: Array },
  isAdmin: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  avatar: { type: String },
});

const Users = mongoose.model("users", usersSchema);
const createNewUser = (userData) => {
  const newUser = new Users(userData);
  return newUser.save();
```

[image: React form component]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

prior code:

```
  const handleAvatarChange = (ev) => {
    let newUserInput = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userInput));
    newUserInput[ev.target.name] = ev.target.files[0].name;
    setUserInput(newUserInput);
  };
```

sulution:

```
  const handleAvatarChange = (ev) => {
    let newUserInput = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userInput));
    newUserInput[ev.target.name] = ev.target.files[0]; // removed ".name" left it as file object
    setUserInput(newUserInput);
  };
```